# UserControl Binding only working in constructor

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, user-controls

I'm trying to bind a `UserControl` to a property in my code.
The binding works in the constructor, but as I try to assign another value to the property after pressing a button, the `UserControl` does not change it's value.

XAML:

```
<UserControl Content="{Binding MainDock, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

The binded property:

```
public UserControl MainDock { get; set; }
```

Constructor:

```
public DBControl()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  this.DataContext = this;

  MarkerControl mc = new MarkerControl();
  MainDock = mc;
}
```

Button method:

```
private void ShowItemsToPrint(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  ItemsToPrintControl sitp = new ItemsToPrintControl();
  MainDock = sitp;
}
```

Comment: MainDock doesn't raise the PropertyChanged event nor does anything implement INotifyPropertyChanged from the code you have provided.

Comment: As a note, setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` is pointless. It only has an effect in TwoWay or OneWayToSource Bindings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be calling `OnPropertyChanged()`:

```
public class MyObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private UserControl _MainDock;
    public UserControl MainDock
    {
        get { return _MainDock; }
        set
        {
            _MainDock = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MainDock));
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

Comment: `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` has nothing to do with the PropertyChanged event.